# How to check current browser name?

Tags: html, firefox, conditional-statements

I know that I can use the following code to detect if the current browser is IE or not:

```html
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

Just wondering if there's something for firefox/chrome?

Thanks

Comment: One word for you: no.

Comment: Here is a conditional for browsers that aren't IE..  `<!--[if !IE]> -->`

Comment: Only IE handles conditional comments. Detecting IE is understandable, but why do you need to detect Firefox specifically?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Not sure if you're asking about HTML, CSS, or JavaScript here.  I'm assuming CSS, but if you would explain what you're trying to do, we can probably suggest a better alternative.

Comment: I am having a problem with fontface CROS problem on firefox. So I would like to serve my fontface locally if user uses firefox but serve fontface on CDN otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a CSS problem, instead of detecting browser better *try to detect the features that a browser supports*.

If you are open to use library, I would suggest to use [**Modernizr**](http://modernizr.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Javascript would be the usual way to detect browser capabilities, but if this is just css, and you only want to apply rules in Firefox try the [Firefox-only `document` at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document)

```css
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    div {
        color : red;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>In firefox this is red!</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kkRyG/)

---

But basically, **no**, there is no way, in plain HTML, to detect the browser and render code based on that (save for IE's conditional comments).

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript object and method

```
navigator.userAgent
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the source code that performed the browser detection:

```
var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
var browserName  = navigator.appName;
var fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); 
var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
var nameOffset,verOffset,ix;

// In Opera, the true version is after "Opera" or after "Version"
if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Opera";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+6);
 if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1) 
   fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In MSIE, the true version is after "MSIE" in userAgent
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("MSIE"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+5);
}
// In Chrome, the true version is after "Chrome" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Chrome"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Chrome";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
}
// In Safari, the true version is after "Safari" or after "Version" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Safari"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Safari";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
 if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1) 
   fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In Firefox, the true version is after "Firefox" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Firefox"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Firefox";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In most other browsers, "name/version" is at the end of userAgent 
else if ( (nameOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ')+1) < 
          (verOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf('/')) ) 
{
 browserName = nAgt.substring(nameOffset,verOffset);
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+1);
 if (browserName.toLowerCase()==browserName.toUpperCase()) {
  browserName = navigator.appName;
 }
}
// trim the fullVersion string at semicolon/space if present
if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(";"))!=-1)
   fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);
if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(" "))!=-1)
   fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);

majorVersion = parseInt(''+fullVersion,10);
if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
 fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); 
 majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
}

document.write(''
 +'Browser name  = '+browserName+'<br>'
 +'Full version  = '+fullVersion+'<br>'
 +'Major version = '+majorVersion+'<br>'
 +'navigator.appName = '+navigator.appName+'<br>'
 +'navigator.userAgent = '+navigator.userAgent+'<br>'
)
```